# Nette framework - accessing , getting services , service classes models, components, helpers from inside presenters or latte templates

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, nette

How to retrieve services in Nette from/inside presenters ( controllers ) to models, templates?

Answer (score 0):

- auto-wiring (dependency injection) -
  [How to autowire ( autowiring ) / get services in Nette from the di dependency injection container context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876839/how-to-autowire-autowiring-get-services-in-nette-from-the-di-dependency-in)
- inside presenter accessing it via $this->getRouter(), $this->getAction(), etc going through such transitive relationships
- inside Latte templates as a $presenter variable , $presenter->getRouter() etc method chaining, respectively $presenter->getContext(), it's deprecated, so rather assigning such not transitively accessible by method chaining if must,  via template variables
- - inside presenter accessing it via $this->context-> ($this->context->getByName(), $this->context->getByType()) , deprecated obsolete way